# Finding all documents in a collection with Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have been fiddling with Mongo, but can't get this simple example to work. I'm simply trying to retrieve all documents in a collection:

```
require 'mongoid'

# configuration ...    

class Category

  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String

end

Category.each do |test|
  puts test.inspect
end
```

I get the error: `undefined method 'each' for Category:Class (NoMethodError).`

Connection to the database is well established, and a collection named `categories` contains a few documents.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Category` indeed doesn't have a method `each` because it's a model class, not a collection. It has, however, several methods that do return collection-like objects. One of them is `all`. So the code should look like this:

```
Category.all.each do |test|
  puts test.inspect
end
```

Comment: Is there any performance impact between Category.all.count and Category.count ?

Comment: @ManojMJ: no, it's exactly the same query.

Comment: It works, but I can't find any references to it in documents o_0?